# Output Java Real memory usage of tomcat jvm in Java 8

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to chart java vm memory usage of a tomcat portal in Java 8.

Java Runtime values are wrong, it only gives a semi acurate estimatives, ex:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

I thought i found a good solution on stackOverflow but it worked only for Java 7:

```
MemoryPoolMXBean testEdenBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().get(3);
MemoryPoolMXBean testSurvivorBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().get(4);
MemoryPoolMXBean testTemurBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans().get(5);

max = testEdenBean.getUsage().getMax() 
    + (testSurvivorBean.getUsage().getMax() * 2) 
    + testTemurBean.getUsage().getMax();
```

Java VisualVM gives me real values because if i start tomcat -Xmx with 1024m i get Max: 1.073.741.824 B which is correct.

How can i get my code to output the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    MemoryMXBean mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
    MemoryUsage heapUsage = mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
    System.out.println("Max heap memory is "+heapUsage.getMax()/1024/1024+" MBytes");
    System.out.println("Used heap memory is "+heapUsage.getUsed()/1024/1024+" MBytes");

    MemoryUsage nonHeapUsage= mbean.getNonHeapMemoryUsage();
    System.out.println("Max non-heap memory is "+nonHeapUsage.getMax()/1024/1024+" MBytes");
    System.out.println("Used non-heap memory is "+nonHeapUsage.getUsed()/1024/1024+" MBytes");
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.